# How to append http to text file for each url

Tags: python

I have a large list of URLs without the http header. 
I am trying to accomplish two things:

1. Read the text file of URLs that do not have the HTTP header exp (www.google.com) and split them into 1000 chunk text files.
2. Append "http://" to each link exp (http://www.google.com)

Currently I am only able to accomplish the first step.

```
from itertools import zip_longest

def grouper(n, iterable, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper(3, 'ABCDEFG', 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return zip_longest(fillvalue= fillvalue, *args)

n = 1000

with open('sites.txt') as f:
    for i, g in enumerate(grouper(n, f, fillvalue=''), 1):
        with open('s_{0}'.format(i), 'w') as fout:
            fout.writelines(g)
```

Comment: This *should* be simply `"http://" + g`, no?

Comment: have you tried adding the `http://` text? I don't see any evidence of it in your code.

Comment: The code you show here will generate an `IndentationError` (actually at least two). Please [edit] your question and fix your code's indentation. We have no way of knowing which errors are relevant and which aren't.

Answer (score 1):

> Append "http://" to each link exp (http://www.google.com)

If you have a list of URL's and want to prepend `https://` to each item, you can use a list comprehension and string formatting.

```
urls = ['https://{}'.format(url) for url in urls]
```

If you have these in a file, split the file on newlines to create a list:

```
with open('sites.txt') as f:
    urls = ['https://{}'.format(url) for url in f.splitlines()]
```

** note: your question has nothing to do with a HTTP headers

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I've understand this question correctly (as it is very unclear)... You can append a string to a every item in a list rather trivially:

```
def addtoeachitem(word, list):
    return [word+item for item in list]
```

Which is the same as writing

```
def addtoeachitem(word, list):
    new = []
    for item in list:
        new.append(word+item)
    return new
```

Obviously this code assumes that everything in the list is a string and it will error out if not. Adapt it for your own needs.